# Best way to find activemq connection leaks

Tags: java, activemq-classic

This is shameful, but we know there are some activemq connection leaks. The code is old and has many twists and turns that makes finding the leaky flow very hard.

We fire many short leaved jobs from batch machine. We know that not all paths are closing the activemq connection properly. When connection is not closed, but job terminates, activemq holds that connection for some amount of time. Ultimately, there are some critical applications which get impacted because activemq max connection limit exceeds.

Is it possible to set connection name or other identifying information so that a non properly closed connection will appear in activemq's log files. This will tell us which log files need to be examined. Sheer number of jobs makes it very hard to find out which exact job caused the problem. However once we know the job, we can deduce enough information from logs to find and fix the connection leaks.

Right now all we see is ip address from which connection originated and since all the jobs originate from same machine, its not helpful to find out who caused the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you add `jms.clientID=something` into your connection URL and turn on DEBUG logging in your conf/log4j.properties, you will get the client id in your debug log on AMQ.  You could then write something to analyze your log and find the AMQ ID for a given clientID and match the logs that way.

If your process is truly exiting though, your connection should be going away at that point (ie you can't keep the connection alive if there's no process to service it).

If you are running on Linux, you can do an netstat -anp | grep 61616 (or whatever your AMQ port is) to see which PIDs still have connections to AMQ, and then another ps to see what those processes are.